# Uncaught exception java.lang.stackoverflowerror using JMeter

Tags: concurrency, jmeter, stack-overflow, jmx, jmeter-plugins

I want to ask about the result when I execute JMeter using CLI mode.

When I'm trying to execute with JMeter in my computer, it's fine, but when I try to execute in CLI mode, it shows this error:

[image: This]

Until now, I still don't know what happened :(

here's the text in the log file
[image]

this is the thread group
[image]

and here the controller
[image]

Comment: attached text from the log with the relevant exception, show your test plan, add more info

Comment: added the log and test plan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests you should check [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file for any suspicious entries.

In the majority of cases [StackOverFlow](https://www.baeldung.com/java-stack-overflow-error) error occurs in JMeter when you have an issue with code/condition evaluation, i.e. check your:

- [If Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller)
- [While Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller)
- [JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
- all places where the code or function or condition is being evaluated

If jmeter.log file doesn't tell the full story you can [increase logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/)

Comment: when i check the log, all of the error is StackOverFlow, and i dont use if controllers, for the thread i'm using Concurrency Thread Group, and the controller, i only use throughtput controller

or is the error happened because i'm not using if controller or while controller?

Comment: It looks like it's not a good idea to limit the number of executions of the samplers under the Concurrency Thread Group using Throughput Controller, you have **Thread iterations limit** which can be used instead. If you want you can report the issue via [jmeter-plugins](https://groups.google.com/g/jmeter-plugins) support forum or if you're a BlazeMeter customer - open a [support ticket](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207491229-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket)

Comment: but if i use **Thread iterations limit**, can i use the report to know how many concurrently user  my server handle?